# Create a list of .TIFF without losing the metadata in R

Tags: r, exif

I have a series of images (`.tiff`) that I would like to put into a list and then convert each image into a data frame.

For that, I have created a list with my images.

```
list.pics<-list.files(path="/Users/Documents/0003SET/000/", pattern="*.tif")
```

By doing that I am losing the metadata that each image has:

```
> class(list.pics)
[1] "character"
```

If I do one image at the time, I get the following,

```
mydf<-read_exif("/Users/Documents/0003SET/000/IMG_0000_1.tif")
class(mydf)
> class(mydf)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

does anyone knows how to create a list of `.tif` files and not lose its metadata on the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't "losing the metadata" - its not trying to read the files, its just returning the filenames:

```
list.pics<-list.files(path="/Users/Documents/0003SET/000/", pattern="*.tif")
```

Hence:

```
> class(list.pics)
[1] "character"
```

if you look at `list.pics[1]` it will be the first file name. If you want the metadata from those files then run `read_exif` on each element of the list. If you are unsure how to do that then an introductory R guide should explain loops and iteration.

But if you are using `read_exif` from the `exifr` package (and there is also one in the `exif` package, you don't say which you are using) you can run that on a vector of filepaths and get a data frame of metadata:

```
> list.pics<-list.files(path="/home/rowlings/Downloads", pattern="\\.tif$",full.names=TRUE)
> read_exif(list.pics)
# A tibble: 5 x 54
  SourceFile     ExifToolVersion FileName    Directory  FileSize FileModifyDate
  <chr>                    <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <int> <chr>         
1 /home/rowling…            11.1 band2.tif   /home/row…  1311858 2018:03:22 21…
2 /home/rowling…            11.1 logged.tif  /home/row…      658 2018:04:29 22…
3 /home/rowling…            11.1 logscale.t… /home/row…      871 2018:04:29 21…
4 /home/rowling…            11.1 r.tif       /home/row…      600 2018:05:08 20…
5 /home/rowling…            11.1 sdat_1290_… /home/row…     1656 2018:08:04 15…
```

Save that in an object and you can get the columns:

```
> meta = read_exif(list.pics)
> meta$Projection
[1]    NA    NA    NA    NA 32767
> meta$Compression
[1] 1 1 5 5 5
```

Note that the `pattern` parameter is a *regular expression*, not a "glob" pattern, so to get all files that end in `.tif` use `pattern="\\.tif$"`
If you have files that end in `.tiff` as well as `.tif` and possibly upper and lower case then it might get a bit more complex, something like:

```
pattern = "\\.[Tt][Ii][Ff][Ff]*$"
```

which matches a dot, then upper or lower case T, I, F, then an optional second upper or lower case F followed by the end of the string (`$`).